# My hosting/website is hacked. Links redirect to russian site

Tags: .htaccess, hosting

I coded a website on my computer, I registered domain, and put my files on 2freehosting.com. While testing this site I noticed something weird. When I clicked on any link on my website a new window poped up with redirection to russian site. The redirection link is: `59016823.g05.info/?p=NGNmN2JjNTYyNm....`

I've read about it, some say `.htaccess` file was hacked (checked, file seems normal), some say server is hacked. Can anyone tell my how to fix this? Will moving to paid hosting solve the problem? Or is it files?

Anybody had this problem before?

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/htaccess-hacked-redirects-to-russion-site Found this, but it's about WordPress and doesn't solve my problem at all. :(

Can I block this website, somehow by `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Well first of all I would try to determine if it is your code or the hosting that is the problem. Try accessing your website locally through your code first. Does it work then? If so then try deleting all your code on your file host site and replace it. Immediately view it. Does it work then or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks John!

I don't know how I never thougth about it before. But this wasn't hosting ads. When I looked into code **via browser** I realized that I obfuscated my code...

That was a problem.

Thanks doe, becouse if not you I don't know if I would ever figure it out.

**TL;DR** - Problem causing this popup was propably hacked or badly working **obfuscator app. Don't** use this obfuscator: http://www.htmlobfuscator.com

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because of your hosting? Almost all free hosting services have built-in ads, and scenario you described looks exactly like a built-in ad. Check html source code of your page in browser (via view-source, not in editor), if you see aditional code, then it's because of your free hosting.